# How to retrieve csv file from a zip response from an API in Nextjs (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, next.js, stream, zip

An external API server A sends a ZIP file, which needs to be unzipped in memory, once unzipped, there exists only 1 csv file. This csv file is then needed to be send to an another API Server. I have tried an attempt wherein I can store the file and then extract, and read things again. But I am looking for a faster way, in which I do not have to write to a file. Here is the Nextjs (Typescript) code I have been working on:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import unzipper from 'unzipper';
import { Readable,Transform  } from 'stream';

private async zipToBlob(zipStream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<FormData> {
        // Convert the ReadableStream to a Node.js readable stream
        const reader = zipStream.getReader();
        const readable = new Readable({
        async read() {
            const { done, value } = await reader.read();
            if (done) {
            this.push(null); // Signal the end of the data
            } else {
            this.push(Buffer.from(value));
            }
        }
        });
    
        // Create a stream to unzip the ZIP file
        const unzipStream = readable.pipe(unzipper.Parse());
        
        // Prepare a FormData object
        const formData = new FormData();
    
        // Promise that resolves with the FormData once the CSV file has been processed
        const formDataPromise = new Promise<FormData>((resolve, reject) => {
            unzipStream.on('entry', (entry) => {
                if (entry.path.endsWith('.csv')) {
                  // Read the CSV entry as a Buffer
                  entry.buffer().then((buffer: Buffer) => {
                    // Append the buffer to the FormData object
                    formData.append('file', new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), "SampleData.csv");
              
                    // Resolve the promise with the FormData object
                    resolve(formData);
                  }).catch(reject);
              
                  // We found our CSV file, so we can ignore the other entries
                  entry.autodrain();
                } else {
                  // Ignore other entries
                  entry.autodrain();
                }
              });
        });
        
        return formDataPromise;
    }
```

Now the issue is that the CSV file that is being sent to another server has machine code rather than csv details.